All URLs that consist of a single word after the domain are redirected to the FilamentPHP login page
All URLs that consist of a single word after the domain are redirected to the FilamentPHP login.
For example, /brands is redirected to /admin/login,
and if within the route it changes to brands/list, it opens correctly.
I also used path('admin').
